# Обработка кликов на разных лейаутах

Tags: android, java

Имеется главный `LinearLayout`, посередине дочерний `LinearLayout` и дальше дочерние элементы.
Назначаю онкликлистенер  (показывать тост, например) на главный `LinearLayout`. Нужно чтобы клик срабатывал только на главном лайоуте и на дочерние элементы не распространялся, как в моем случае. То есть у меня клик срабатывает и на дочернем `LinearLayout`, но мне это не нужно..
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно сделать?

Comment: Ну чо опять мне отвечать?!

Comment: Попробуйте OnTouchListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать у дочерних элементов setClickable(false)

Хотя есть и костыльный вариант, установить всем дочерним элементам clickListener, а в нем ничего не обрабатывать - но это говнокод, если придете к такому варианту, **НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ**

Comment: Поставил пустой кликлистенер второй лайнеарлейаут, остальные элементы можно не трогать и работать с ними обычным способом...